# How to insert multiple values eg JSON encoding in value parameter of put() method in leveldb in c++

Tags: c++, json, nosql, leveldb

I have been trying to insert key value pairs in database  using leveldb and it works fine with simple strings. However if I want to store multiple attributes for a key or for example use JSON encoding , how can it be done in c++ . In Node.js leveldb package it can be done by specifying the encoding . Really can't figure this out

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just a string, so I'm not completely sure where you're coming from here…

If you have some sort of in-memory representation of JSON you'll need to serialize it before writing it to the database and parse it when reading.

Comment: i was not asking JSON specifically, but more like how to add multiple attribute for a key in leveldb using c++

Comment: You have to handle that yourself; leveldb operates at a lower level of abstraction.